# Play array of videos without videos getting played together at once in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am having an array of video urls playing in full screen. I have left and right swipe in the view controller. The problem is once I start playing a video and swipe left or right the current video doesn't stop playing and the next video start playing. Old video plays along with new videos audio.

Below is my initial video playing code.

```
avPlayer = AVQueuePlayer.init()
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
avPlayer!.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
avPlayer?.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

avPlayer?.play()
```

On left/right swipe.

```
if avPlayer != nil
{
    if (avPlayer?.rate != 0 && avPlayer?.error == nil)
    {
         avPlayer!.pause()
         avPlayer!.advanceToNextItem()
         avPlayerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
 }
```

After this again the first code part is executed.

Comment: When you swipe are you creating a new AVPlayerLayer in the view or are you using the same one over and over?

Comment: You claim you are using an array of URLs but in the provided code you are not using them. Benefit of `AVQueuePlayer` is that it provides the "queue" to manage the playlist for you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer/1389345-init. You are providing single item and directly to the player.